# PHP string expression error: what is happening here?

Tags: php, operators

The expression

```
"a".(strlen('ab')-strlen('a'))
```

evaluates to `a1` as expected.

But if I accidentally omit parentheses,

```
"a".strlen('ab')-strlen('a')
```

evaluates to `-1`. What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you might also get a Warning for non-numeric value when you omit the "()".

As a normal mathematical rule, the brackets are solved first so in the

> ```
> "a".(strlen('ab')-strlen('a'))
> ```

`strlen('ab')` is 2 and,
`strlen('a')` is 1,
so 2-1= 1 and it gets concated with 'a' so becomes 'a1'.

And when you remove the parentheses,

```
"a".strlen('ab')-strlen('a')
```

then it executes left to right so

1. `strlen('ab')` concate's with 'a' which gives a2
2. then 'a2' which is non-numeric is substracted with `strlen('a')` which is 1. so warning is displayed.
3. But 'a2' is forced to be converted to numeric, thus becomes 0 so finally
4. 0 - 1 = -1

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I looked up PHP conversions in the manual and found that a2 is converted to 0 as an arbitrary decision (rather than raising an error message). A strange choice in the design of PHP, since errors can be suppressed just by prefixing an expression with the @ character.

Answer (score 3):

`"a".strlen('ab')-strlen('a')` is processed from left to right like:

- `"a".strlen('ab')` becomes **string** "a2"
- Now you have `'a2' - 1`

You cannot substract from a string, so **string** `'a2'` is casted to **int** thus becoming `0`

- Now you have `0 - 1` which is **`-1`**.

Related articles: [operators precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), [string conversions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

Answer (score 0):

The

```
"a".(strlen('ab')-strlen('a'))
```

operation first calculates the difference of the length of strings and then adds the result to `"a"`, converting `1` into `"1"` in the process.

The

```
"a".strlen('ab')-strlen('a')
```

operation adds the length of `'ab'` (2) to `"a"`, resulting `"a2"`. After that, from this String, the length of `"a"` (1) is subtracted, but since subtraction can only happen between numbers in PHP, therefore `"a2"` converted into `0` and subtracting `1` from here yields `-1`.